# Distance attained by a function

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity, compactness

Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ and let $x\in \mathbb R^n$. Then $\exists y_0\in A$ such that $d(x,y_0)=d(x,A)$ if

1. $A$ is a non-empty subset of $\mathbb R^n$.
2. $A$ is a non-empty closed subset of $\mathbb R^n$.
3. $A$ is a non-empty compact subset of $\mathbb R^n$.
4. $A$ is a non-empty bounded subset of $\mathbb R^n$.

In my opinion, option 3. is correct. If we define a function $f:A\to \mathbb R$ by $f(y)=d(x,y)$ for all $y\in A$, then $f$ is continuous (in fact uniformly continuous) and so attained its bounds if $A$ is compact. Since $d(x,A)=\inf\{d(x,y): y\in A\}$, there fore there is $y_0\in A$ such that $f(y_0)=d(x,A)$. But is the option 2 is wrong? I could not find any clue. Please help to find the answer.

Comment: What is the definition of $d(x,A)$ you are using? If it is one involving $\inf$ (as I would wager), then you can use the sequential characterization of an infimum and see how this relates to closed sets.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Construct a sequence of $y_{n}\in A$ with the following property, for each $y_{n}$, $d(y_{n}, x)\leq d(A, x)+\frac{1}{n}$.  Now, does $y_{n}$ converge? can you adjust it if necessary to make it converge? does it converge to something in $A$?

Hints on specific numbers:

1) What if $A=\mathbb{Q}$ and $x\notin \mathbb{Q}$?

2) If $A$ is closed then $A\cap \{y: d(x, y)\leq d(x, A)+\frac{1}{n}\}$ is a compact set.

3) Compact implies sequentially compact...

4) What if $A=\mathbb{Q}\cap [0, 1]$ $x\in (0, 1)\setminus \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Your thoughts on $3$ are correct.  The distance function is continuous.  You can use $3$ to prove $2$ using the hint.

Comment: 2) is false if you replace $x$ with a set $X$ and say there is a $y\in A$ so that $d(y,X)=d(A, X)$.